# In The Librarians why didn't this event in season 4 change the present?

Tags: time-travel, the-librarians

In season 2 episode 10 when they're in the time machine room, Flynn says:

> All their owners tried to change history and got caught in temporal loops because you can never ever ever violate causality. The very first time traveller learned that if you change any event in the past, any event of significance in the past, your timeline collapses, your entire history wiped out.

However in season 4 episode 5, at the end they send [Darrington Dare](https://thelibrarians.fandom.com/wiki/Darrington_Dare) back in time. As a result of their meeting, rather than dying the next day, he continued to live for another 62 years. Yet there doesn't seem to be any difference to the current timeline, other than an addition to Darrington's page in the book of librarians.

How come the timeline didn't collapse?

Comment: The show is entertaining,  but I'd never expect consistency from it.

Comment: Also, FLynn might not be considered a reliable narrator if any.

Answer (score 0):

Several thoughts come to mind

One he traveled into the future then returned to his own present he did not attempt to alter the past so causality does not apply

Two his death or lack of death is just not a significant enough event

or three the timeline did collapse, the universe the viewers have grown to know and love was unceremoniously destroyed and replaced by a completely new universe in which everything is precisely the same except for a very few small changes

Comment: Causality always applies, what you mean is that he didn't violate it